# How to use MySQL database in visual c# 2010

Tags: c#, mysql, xna

I need to use a database in my xna 4.0 game that will save data such as username, etc. can you give me an example on how to connect to a MySQL database and as well as an insert statement. thank you !

Comment: Umm. you want an example of an insert statement? Is it really that hard to google up some SQL syntax examples? We can help fix problems with your existing code here, but we're not here to teach you something you could very easily learn yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a walk through and wrapper class for mysql in c#.
http://iseesharp.blogspot.com/2005/09/mysql-with-c.html

Usage:

```
DbWrapper myWrapper = new DbWrapper("localhost", "CS",
    "iseesharp", "seesharper");
myWrapper.Connect();

myWrapper.AddUser("Rowan", "ISeeSharp");
if (myWrapper.UserExists("rowan"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Something's weird here");
}
else
    if (myWrapper.UserExists("Rowan"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("I exist, therefore I think!");
}

myWrapper.Disconnect();
```